# How can I multiplex Ethernet signals?

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet

I want to multiplex ethernet signals from a router via (RJ45) to two outgoing RJ45. Mechanical relays seems a feasible solution but they have bandwidth limitations. [This IC seems to be a close match.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts3l501e.pdf)

The rough diagram:

[image]

The IC doesn't support any negative voltage since a quick google search reveals that Ethernet signals are +2.5v and -2.5v differential signals. The purpose of the circuit is to switch between two networks using an MCU in circuit based on some criteria.

Any suggestion?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145124/discussion-on-question-by-ijaz-ahmad-ethernet-signals-multiplexing); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: You want to occasionally switch between two ports with only one being active at a time? Or you want to use both ports at the same time?

Comment: Only one port active at a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a somewhat hard problem.

Connecting twisted-pair Ethernet directly to chips will usually result in a blown chip sooner or later. No chip out there can really take the kind of abuse that an Ethernet line can deliver. It doesn't matter what chip it is - switch or not.

Another problem is isolation: All those RJ45 jacks can be at common mode potentials that differ by 10s of Volts. So, if you galvanically connect them to *anything*, that "thing" has to deal with potential differences and do level translation.

In practice, the most robust way of doing this kind of a switch is by terminating each port in a magjack and a PHY chip, and doing the switching in either an actual Ethernet switch chip, or an FPGA. Most switch chips have external management interface via SPI or I2C, so that's how you'd enable and disable downstream ports to emulate toggling the "switch" between two ports. The only downside to switch chips is that they typically store-and-forward, so add a latency of about a packet duration between input and output. In most cases that's inconsequential, so perhaps in yours too.

The FPGA would be more design work. It can be fairly low-end, since there's not a lot of things it'd need to do to pass data around. A small clock-difference compensating buffer is needed in the FPGA, but it can be pretty much the smallest RAM element they offer, and you probably only need to store a couple dozen symbols in it.

Otherwise, mechanical relays are a reasonable way to go. They may not necessarily pass Ethernet compliance tests, but if they work reasonably for your one-off application, then that's all there's to it. Finding a couple of small reed relays that would do this job shouldn't be too hard. To maintain signal integrity, the reed tubes in each pair should be close together. Relays that enclose two reeds in a common coil would do the job. Even better if you can find a double form-C contact reed: that's a 2-pole, 2-throw reed with the reed tubes next to each other, and will offer perhaps the best signal integrity out of any relay not purpose-built to deal with twisted-pair Ethernet.

Such relays can be bought surplus on eBay. Look for e.g. Electrol reed relays. Many of them have more than one reed in a coil, and many also have form-C contacts.

Comment: I'd say a single Ethernet switch IC with three copper PHYs is mildly easier than having three PHY chips and an FPGA in between.

Comment: @Justme You're right, that's another option. It's more intrusive, as switch chips are mostly store-and-forward, but less design work. I'll add that to the answer, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica  Really nice reply and seems like relays are sophisticated option. Just one query, there are 4 pairs in Ethernet cable. Will it be okay if i only disconnect one of the cable e.g + in every pair (Tx+, Rx+). As the signals are differential or should all 8 wires be disconnected? Disconnecting 4 wires will reduce number of relays. Also since reed relays have current limitation so any idea whats the amount of current that flows through Ethernet wires (non PoE)?

Comment: I have marked you reply as answer. Thanks for the detail reply. I have moved my above concern to next thread. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661806/ethernet-signal-current-on-data-lines-and-communication-connectivity-on-each-of

Answer (score 0):

Twisted pair Ethernet is transformer isolated, as long as you aren't pushing the limits on distance you can almost certainly get away with adding some additional isolation transformers in the path.

You can use the centre taps on these isolation transformers to apply a DC bias of half the supply voltage to the signals. I believe this should be enough to keep the signals within the range the IC can handle.