# Ethernet signal current on data lines and communication connectivity on each of pair

Tags: relay, ethernet

This post is linked to my previous post ([here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661664/how-can-i-multiplex-ethernet-signals?noredirect=1)) whose scope is complete so I am opening a separate thread for my next concern.

There are four wire pairs in an Ethernet cable. If we want to disconnect Ethernet signals via reed relays, will it be enough if we only disconnect one of the wires in each pair, e.g. the + in every pair (Tx+, Rx+, Dx+: [list](https://content.spiceworksstatic.com/service.community/p/post_images/0000151583/56c68556/attached_image/ethernet_10_100_1000.jpg)) as the signals are differential, or should all eight wires be disconnected?

Reed relays are a bit expensive; disconnecting four wires will reduce the number of relays. Also, reed relays have a current limitation. Any idea what the amount of current is that flows through Ethernet wires (non-PoE)?

Comment: What's wrong with compact (signal type) DPDT relays?

Comment: @TimWilliams Do you guarantee they pass Gigabit Ethernet without problems?

Comment: Gig isn't very high bandwidth, it's only slightly more than 100BASE-T.

Comment: @TimWilliams If by "slightly" you actually mean "double", then it should be fine. But generic relays are not intended for signals with tens of MHz of bandwidth anyway, as they don't have the differential impedance and are thus causing a discontinuity on the transmission line, which again causes reflections.

Comment: @Justme According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet the symbol rates are both 125Mbps, with more lanes and bits/symbol providing the higher bandwidth in the one case. Both require bandwidth under 100MHz. Ethernet is quite insensitive to impedance mismatch and stub length; a non-RF type relay might not have controlled impedances but the lengths are short (<2cm?) enough not to care.

Comment: @Justme if your cables are short, you can use pretty much anything, from my experiements with very ordinary relays and cables about 5 m.  I've used lots of this kind of thing for various software testing systems (introducing cable breaks, timing "plug-in to packet-flow" and so on).  I'm certain relections, untwist segments and so on will cause problems with cables approaching ether limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't disconnect one half of the ethernet cable.  Regarding current, it is negligible for pure-signal ethernet.  Basic POE IEEE 802.3af-2003 is 350 mA on pair; later varieties up to about 1 A. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet)).

Your posts are difficult to understand about exactly what signals you have access to (just outside the RJ45?), and what kinds of tests you want to perform.  It would really help if you made your requirements at lot clearer.

If it is strictly "outside the device", and you have full distance requirements and you have full speed requirements and your tests are, say, on the electrical performance: then your problem really needs careful consideration.

If you've got short cables, no interconnects or patch panels, and you're not needing every last performance requirement to be fully met, then you have an easy problem.

The easy problem is this easy:
I put this together on my bench to try it this morning, with the basic "economy relays" I had available (Omron LY2N-J) which are DPDT, needing four relays for four pairs.  It worked fine for all basic preliminary tests at 100baseT on 5 metre cable: no error count on the interface.

[image]

As noted in comments, many DPDT signal relays are available, at circa €1.5/unit from large suppliers.  Cheaper than reed-relays and DPDT means you need half as many.

Here is just one of the >700 types available on a major supplier.  Note you can get latching versions, so you only use power on the relay when it's changing.  Depending on your application that might be important.

[image]

Image source: [Kemet EC2/EE2 datasheet](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_R7002_EC2_EE2.pdf)

Comment: Just wants to say thanks for creating test environment and performing validation. Accepting your answer with thanks.